# how to add dynamic rows in html having select fields in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to develop UI page, like naukari add/edit skill, which is able to add dynamic rows with select fields, after submit store the data in db, when we click on add/edit skill same data should be there in the fields ,there is possible to add new rows also.I am adding image here same like this i need to implement same like this in angular Js

[image]

please any one help me implement this, provide some code base it is very helpful for me.

Comment: can you show some code demonstrating what you've tried?  "I need some code" isn't a very good question for this site.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906145/how-to-add-the-rows-dynamically-with-angularjs.It may Help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an array, put it into ng-repeat and push an object into that array onclick of add button.
This must be helpful. http://www.shanidkv.com/blog/angularjs-dynamic-table-addremove-action

Comment: Thank you @Ushma Joshi for helping me.I resolved the issue.