# How to create new row dynamically in html

Tags: html, css, angular, dynamic

I am creating a website in that I'm using the Flipkart API for getting the list of products. But when products are shown on site they are not showing in its well-formatted view as I have created the design for it.
I want to show only 4 products per row, but now I'm confused how to do that please help me.

```
<div class="container-fluid">   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column" ng-repeat="data in flipkart">
            <div class="cards card1">
                <a href="" ng-click="userSearchDetails(data.productBaseInfoV1.title)">
                <img src="{{data.productBaseInfoV1.imageUrls.200x200}}" class="img-responsive" style="padding-top: 3px;">
                <strong> <p>Rs {{data.productBaseInfoV1.flipkartSpecialPrice.amount}} </p></strong> </a>
                <h6><strong>{{data.productBaseInfoV1.title}}</strong></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
div {
    margin: 0px;
}
.body-class {
    background-color:#FAFAFA;
}
.row {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear: both; 
    margin-left:  45px;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    max-height: 50%;
    margin:10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

h6 {
    padding:3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please check this link It may help you :    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906145/how-to-add-the-rows-dynamically-with-angularjs

Comment: no, it's not what I want. I'm getting elements dynamically from the Flipkart's server, I'm not manually adding it.

Comment: Form the Flipkart's server elements are coming from which format??

Comment: Image and some text. Image is having 200*200 dimensions

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of Angular's 1.x version's in-built variable `$index` available inside a `ng-repeat` construct to get the current index.

In order to restrict just 4 cards per line, you could do something as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid">   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column" ng-repeat="data in flipkart">
            <div class="cards card1">
                <a href="" ng-click="userSearchDetails(data.productBaseInfoV1.title)">
                <img src="{{data.productBaseInfoV1.imageUrls.200x200}}" class="img-responsive" style="padding-top: 3px;">
                <strong> <p>Rs {{data.productBaseInfoV1.flipkartSpecialPrice.amount}} </p></strong> </a>
                <h6><strong>{{data.productBaseInfoV1.title}}</strong></h6>
            </div>
            <!-- Add a conditional <br /> tag after every fourth product card -->
            <br ng-if="($index+1)%4===0" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```